# Check whether an app is installed in a paired device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Is there a way to search another devices installed application using bluetooth? Actual requirement is, is there a way to search the paired devices installed applications.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but this is not possible, unless you specifically have your own app on both sides and are somehow enabling this yourself. There is nothing built into Android to allow an arbitrary device to attack another arbitrary device (e.g., get at private information like installed applications).